# Visual basic 6.0 setup toolkit has stop working

Tags: vb6

I have created an application in Visual Basic.
After that, I make a setup using **Package and Deployment Wizard**
But when I tried to install it I got an error 
"**Visual basic 6.0 setup toolkit has stop working**"
Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The old setup toolkit makes installers that are pretty much unsupported in modern versions of Windows - it would be better to use something like WiX (http://sourceforge.net/projects/wix/) to create a proper msi installer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like that once. It was caused because the Pack/De[loy wizard was using the wrong version of setup.exe. Earlier I had made some kind of error (do not know what it was), it caused VB6 to lose the location of the setup file for Pack/Deploy so it ASKED me with "Can not find file..." Browse for it". Well, when I was browseing I chose the wrong Setup.exe (the one in Windows\system32\setup.exe) and it has held on to the path ever since. I cant seem to find a way to change it to correct one. I get by the problem by manually copying the correct setup to the package after I make it.