# VB6 installer on 64-bit OS on x64 CPU

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I had a VB6 application setup file that was working perfectly on Windows Server 2003 32-bit OS.
Now the customer has moved to Windows Server 2012 64-bit on Intel Xeon CPU E5 which is x64-based processor.

The installer gives the error:

> Setup Bootstrap for Visual Basic Setup Toolkit has stopped working

The error occurs when the installer is Copying Files and Processing `VB6STKIT.DLL`

What is the solution?

Comment: I would probably have them run it in a virtual machine if possible.

Comment: Some people think you should recreate the install setup :(  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631486/visual-basic-6-0-setup-toolkit-has-stop-working

Comment: adjust the bootstrapper (the hard way) or use this: [Inno Setup Toolbar Advanced for VB6](https://sourceforge.net/projects/innotoolbarvb6/)